# How can I set an event listener to listen to a text box from the HTML Source code using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, event-listener

Currently developing a Firefox Addon in JavaScript. It scans a webpage for specific things like email addresses. Is there a way of being able to get it to read the source code of a website and set an event listener to a text box which can then detect whether a user is entering an email address in a text box on any website. Not sure whether this is possible in JavaScript as I am new to it. I need to be able to display an alert if the user types in an email address on a website but as this will be running from a Firefox Addon. Almost like it would display if you were using it for validation purposes on a website. But as this is from a Firefox Addon it doesn't quite work the same way.
I have looked at GreaseMonkey but its quite confusing and when trying to find specifically whether it could be done I have got stuck.

How could I implement this would be great or even whether it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].onkeypress = function () {
            if (this.value.match(/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/)) {
                // do something
                alert('Looks like an email address!');
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/49cny/

Comment: Thank you this was very informative. It works fine but the email address has not been fully completed before it displays the alert. Is there a way of displaying the alert once the user has finished their input?

Comment: `.co` IS a valid country TLD, therefore the email address is considered valid before the user types `.com`

Comment: or, you could validate only after the input box loses focus. Change `onkeypress` to `onblur`

Comment: I did try using blur but when switching tabs etc it displays the alert again.

Comment: i have a question regarding this...what if there is already an event handler set...then what will happen, will it replace it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `event listener` like:

**Syntax**

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture, aWantsUntrusted Non-standard]); // Gecko/Mozilla only
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

**For example**

```
document.getElementById('inputid').addEventListener("keypress", function(){/* Your code */}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `jQuery .keyPress() function` Below is an example...Where `#target` is the `ID` of the `Textbox`.

```
var i=0;
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
i++;
console.log("Kep Pressed: " + i);
}
```